# Postgres Command Line tool for Import/Exporting data/ddl

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ddl

For Postgres is there any sort of command line utilities that allow a database to be "dumped to a file" and that allow that same database dump to be imported?

I know this can be done through PGAdmin, but I need to be able to do this on the cmd line.

Comment: Did you try the `psql` tool which ships with the server?

Comment: If anyone want Export/Import for whole DB then look at [Export and Import of PostgresSQL using pgAdmin III](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39167526/1045444)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, take a look into `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: Thanks but you could have given a simple example (one line of code for `pg_dump` and another for `pg_restore`), that would have been much more helpful

Comment: `pg_restore -U postgres -W -d dvdrental /tmp/dvdrental.tar`
-U is username
-W is password (not put password in this line, it will appear a promt)
-d is database
and finally specify path of file

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the way to do this is the pg_dump, pg_dumpall and pg_restore commands. In fact, I think pg_admin actually calls those commands itself. It doesn't actually have backup/restore built in but is just a wrapper.