# Export DB with PostgreSQL's PgAdmin-III

Tags: sql, postgresql, export, database-backups, pgadmin

How to export a Postgresql db into SQL that can be executed into other `pgAdmin`?

- Exporting as backup file, doesn't work when there's a difference in version
- Exporting as SQL file, does not execute when tried to run on a different `pgAdmin`

I tried exporting a DB with `pgAdmin III` but when I tried to execute the SQL in other `pgAdmin` it throws error in the SQL, when I tried to "restore" a Backup file, it says there's a difference in version that it can't do the import/restore.

So is there a "safe" way to export a DB into standard SQL that can be executed plainly in `pgAdmin` SQL editor, regardless of which version it is?

Comment: So I guess you tried something like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599696/use-pg-restore-to-restore-from-a-newer-version-of-postgresql ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using the 'psql' however nothing happens, no error, but the DB is not updated with the tables ,etc.

Comment: So I am thinking of a more generic approach, a SQL backup that can be executed in any version of postgreSQL

Comment: How do you try to run SQL dump in pgAdmin? You copy-paste it into SQL console? what exactly error do you have? do you try to export/import content of some system tables or sth?

Comment: "throws an error" should never appear in your question. **What error?**. What PgAdmin-III version and PostgreSQL version? When you say it "doesn't work" when there's a different version, how **exactly* does it not work?

Comment: What an awful tool in this case. In phpMyadmin, the creation of a dump is really intuitive, people don't need to go on StackOverflow and even after that having problems!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try to use PgAdmin-III for this. Use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` directly if possible.

Use the version of `pg_dump` from the destination server to dump the origin server. So if you're going from (say) 8.4 to 9.2, you'd use 9.2's `pg_dump` to create a dump. If you create a `-Fc` custom format dump (recommended) you can use `pg_restore` to apply it to the new database server. If you made a regular SQL dump you can apply it with `psql`.

See [the manual on upgrading your PostgreSQL cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html).

Now, if you're trying to *downgrade*, that's a whole separate mess.

You'll have a hard time creating an SQL dump that'll work in *any* version of PostgreSQL. Say you created a VIEW that uses a `WITH` query. That won't work when restored to PostgreSQL 8.3 because it didn't support `WITH`. There are tons of other examples. If you must support old PostgreSQL versions, do your development on the oldest version you still support and then export dumps of it for newer versions to load. You cannot sanely develop on a new version and export for old versions, it won't work well if at all.

More troubling, developing on an old version won't always give you code that works on the new version either. Occasionally new keywords are added where support for new specification features are introduced. Sometimes issues are fixed in ways that affect user code. For example, if you were to develop on the (ancient and unsupported) 8.2, you'd have lots of problems with implicit casts to text on 8.3 and above.

Your best bet is to test on all supported versions. Consider setting up automated testing using something like Jenkins CI. Yes, that's a pain, but it's the price for software that improves over time. If Pg maintained perfect backward and forward compatibility it'd never improve.

Answer (score 3):

#### Export/Import with pg_dump and psql

1.Set PGPASSWORD

```
export PGPASSWORD='123123123';
```

2.Export DB with pg_dump

```
pg_dump -h <<host>> -U <<username>> <<dbname>> > /opt/db.out
```

/opt/db.out is dump path. You can specify of your own.

3.Then set again PGPASSWORD of you another host. If host is same or password is same then this is not required.

4.Import db at your another host

```
psql -h <<host>> -U <<username>> -d <<dbname>> -f /opt/db.out
```

If username is different then find and replace with your local username in db.out file. And make sure on username is replaced and not data.

If you still want to use PGAdmin then see procedure below.

#### Export DB with PGAdmin:

Select DB and click Export.

1. File Options

   - Name DB file name for you local directory
   - Select Format - Plain
2. Ignore Dump Options #1
3. Dump Options #2

   - Check `Use Insert Commands`
4. Objects

   - Uncheck tables if you don't want any

#### Import DB with PGAdmin:

1. Create New DB.
2. By keeping selected DB, Click `Menu->Plugins->PSQL Console`
3. Type following command to import DB

   ```
   \i /path/to/db.sql
   ```

If you want to export Schema and Data separately.

**Export Schema**

1. File Options

   - Name schema file at you local directory
   - Select Format - Plain
2. Dump Options #1

   - Check `Only Schema`
   - Check `Blobs` (By default checked)

**Export Data**

1. File Options

   - Name data file at you local directory
   - Select Format - Plain
2. Dump Options #1

   - Check `Only Data`
   - Check `Blobs` (By default checked)
3. Dump Options #2

   - Check `Use Insert Commands`
   - Check `Verbose messages` (By default checked)

**Note:** It takes time to Export/Import based on DB size and with PGAdmin it will add some more time.