# Export and import table dump (.sql) using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin

I have pgAdmin version `1.16.1` installed on my machine.

For exporting a table dump, I do:

Right click on the table => Choose `backup` => Set `Format` to `Plain` => Save the file as `some_name.sql`

Then I remove the table.

Ok, now I need to import the backup I just created from `some_name.sql` into the database.

How am I supposed to do this? I can't find any clear instructions on how to import table's `.sql` dump into database using pgAdmin.

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: If anyone want for whole DB then look [Export and Import of PostgresSQL with pgAdmin III](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39167526/1045444)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

1. In pgAdmin, select the required target schema in object tree (<kbd>databases</kbd> -><kbd>your_db_name</kbd> -> <kbd>schemas</kbd> -> <kbd>your_target_schema</kbd>)
2. Click on Plugins/PSQL Console  (in top-bar)
3. Write `\i /path/to/yourfile.sql`
4. Press enter

Comment: Thanks but... `Alternatively, you can open SQL file in query window and simply run it ` 

 When I am trying this, I got error that there is syntax error at line where is writed: `COPY my_table (id, name) FROM stdin;
.....
`

Comment: OH, sorry for that, I did not realize that dump will use COPY and not inserts. The first option should however work.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it didn't works for me. Then I go with @OTARIKI comment & it works. Excellent OTARIKI. I'll upvote to your comment.

Comment: @OO7, Thank you, but however, my comment about that "something not works". Really, @Tomas's answer is `excellent`  and it works for me :)

Comment: Windows example: If you have a PostgreSQL backup file at `C:\database.backup`, then you can start the import with `\i /database.backup` .

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question. What is a target scheme? Where is the object tree? What if you don't have those already?

Comment: @TomasGreif All questions about "I can't find how to import table's .sql dump into database using pgAdmin" redirect here, but this doesn't really answer that question.

Comment: @Abdull only if postgresql is also installed on C I believe.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to import my sql dump. Just a side node: at least for pgAdmin 1.16.1 on the mac its `pgAdmin3/PSQL Console`. However it seems like the direct terminal command is something like `'/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql' --host 'localhost' --port 5432 --username 'postgres' 'correcthorsebatterystaple' && exit || sleep 5 && exit`

Comment: if you are facing the problem with copy statements, you can change it to insert statements in dump options window @Oto Shavadze.

Comment: When trying pgAdmin responses: permission denied for C. \i C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\osakeekstra_2022_16_05.sql
C:: Permission denied

Comment: @ManikantaB, how to replace copy with insert statements?

Answer (score 30):

An another way, you can do it easily with CMD on Windows

Put your installed version (mine is 11).

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\
```

and run simple query

```
psql -U <postgre_username> -d <db_name> < <C:\path\data_dump.sql>
```

enter password then wait the final console message.

**Note:** Make sure to remove <> from the above query except for the < between db_name & file path.

Example: `psql -U postgres -d dumb_db < D:\db_dump.sql`

Comment: This is import.

Comment: Just use opposite arrows, `... db_name < ... path` import, `... db_name > path...` export

Answer (score 27):

Using PgAdmin
step 1:
select schema and right click and go to Backup..[image]

step 2:
Give the file name and click the backup button.

[image]

step 3:
In detail message copy the backup file path.

[image]

step 4:

Go to other schema and right click and go to Restore. (see step 1)

step 5:

In popup menu paste aboved file path to filename category and click Restore button.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I however selected the file from the file picker after clicking on "..." and changing the format to "sql". But it works. Easiest solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Follow the steps in pgadmin

host-DataBase-Schemas- public (click right) CREATE script- open file -(choose xxx.sql) , then click on the option execute query write result to file  -export data file ok- then click in save.its all. it work to me.

note: error in version command script [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HTW7.png)de sql over pgadmin  can be search, example:
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f21/campo-tipo-datetime-postgresql-245389/

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. English is not great but it is understandable and works.

Answer (score 9):

Click "query tool" button in the list of "tool".

[image]

And then click the "open file" image button in the tool bar.

[image]

Comment: You'll also need to hit [Execute]

Comment: This gives me the error "File type not supported".

Answer (score 2):

If you have Git bash installed, you can do something like this:

```
/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/psql -U <pg_role_name> -d <pg_database_name> < <path_to_your>.sql
```