# pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive error in PostgreSQL using Pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to open a SQL Script of PostgreSQL (.sql file) that contains the Create Database and INSERT statements but when I try to restore the database using PgAdmin 4 it gives me error stating "pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive" . I selected the following fields in the Restore Database dialog box:

**Format** - as Custom or tar

**Filename** - C:\Users\parwa\Desktop\DWBI\Assignment - 2(Chinook SQL - 2)\Question Content\Chinook_PostgreSql.sql

**Number of Jobs** - (left this field blank)

**Role name** - Postgres

I am not sure why it's giving me this error. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export and import table dump (.sql) using pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736345/export-and-import-table-dump-sql-using-pgadmin)

Comment: Why did you select "**Custom or tar**" if the file clearly is a SQL script? Just run the script

Answer (score 3):

In pgAdmin 4 the Restore Dialog is a UI interface to the pg_restore command line utility (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html), I don't think it deals with sql files directly.

The documentation says

> You can use the Query Tool to play back the script created during a plain-text backup made with the Backup dialog. For more information about backing up or restoring, please refer to the documentation for pg_dump or pg_restore.

Which indicates that to restore the sql file you have you need to use the Query Tool instead.

Tools -> Query Tool and you can open or paste the file in there and run it.